# How can i recursively find with cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I have a relation set up like this:

```
class Geocache extends AppModel {
    var $belongsTo = 'User';
    var $hasMany = 'Log';
}
class Log extends AppModel {
    var $belongsTo = array('User','Geocache');
}
class User extends AppModel {
    var $hasMany = array('Geocache','Log');
}
```

and a `$this->Geocache->find('first');` returns:

```
Array
(
    [Geocache] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86
            [user_id] => 3
            [name] => Hejssa
            //...
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [username] => Ahtenus
            //...
        )

    [Log] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 12
                    // How do i retrive the username and such from the User table together with this?
                    [geocache_id] => 86
                    //...
                )
            //...
        )
)
```

How can I also get the User data for each log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [recursive property](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive) to 2.

```
$this->Geocache->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'recursive' => 2
    )
);
```

A word of warning: setting recursive to anything over 1 will easily bloat the results even in a small database. In this case it will pull the Geocache data again for each log entry. You should use [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) to limit the results to only those tables and fields that you need.

Comment: As soon as I set 'recursive' to anything more than 1 i get this wierd error: `Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /var/www/ccache/app/models/geocache.php on line 94` Do you know what the reason for this could be?

Comment: Can you post line 94 (and surroundings) of that file?

Comment: Sorry, mixed up the model and the controller and was looking at the wrong file. I'll fix it myself, but thanks anyway.